# Is there any way to apply SwiftLint to SwiftPackages

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swiftlint

I'm struggling to find a way to apply SwiftLint to my swift packages. 
But after searching a lot, I couldn't find any way.

I use micro application architecture, which leads me to many micro packages. I am looking for a way to use `SwiftLint` for my swift packages.

Comment: It will be supported at the release of Xcode 13.3. Here is the corresponding [**change logs**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_3-release-notes#Swift-Package-Manager)

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem. The current version of SPM does not support Run Scripts so you can't run `SwiftLint` in a way like on the main project. But future versions of SPM will support it.

Currently, I use the command line to find all the issues. This is not very convenient but something.

In the package folder:

```
swiftlint --config [path to swiftlint.yml] > [path to file to save a report]
```

e.g.

```
swiftlint --config ~/Desktop/swiftlint.yml > ~/Desktop/swiftlintreport.txt
```

Comment: It will be supported at the release of Xcode 13.3. Here is the corresponding [**change logs**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_3-release-notes#Swift-Package-Manager)

Comment: since Xcode 13.3 is out, I’m also struggling of this, is there any clear approach how to use `swiftlint` with SPM with proper way?

Answer (score 0):

When I'm working on a SPM package I usually create an Xcode project that locally imports the package and use that project to work on the project.

This allows me to run stuff like `SwiftLint`. It's also handy to remember to use the correct access control modifiers.

You can see an example in [this project of mine.](https://github.com/EmilioPelaez/EventHierarchy)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) just updated main repository, commit [3fd1573](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/commit/3fd1573c572f5d960d8e8b3bc46bc229c969ddcb) added support through SwiftPM & `Run Build Tool Plug-ins`. Take in account that you need Xcode 14 or later to use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a SPM plugin in your `package.swift` file:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint", from: "0.52.4") //  add here
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "MyPackage", package: "MyPackage")
            ],
            plugins: [
                .plugin(name: "SwiftLintPlugin", package: "SwiftLint")  //  use here
            ]
        )
    ]
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this adds like 4 minutes of build time on a clean build on a M1 Max :/

Comment: Yes, you should try to have this run occasionally like for PR or on the build server.